# content query web part xsl regex

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts

I'm trying to transform an incoming text property in my XSL using a regular expression, something similar to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(@Telephone, '^*.{}')" />
```

but this does not seem to work. I've read blogs where they delve into analyze-string things and such which I don't understand.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: I don't think MIcrosoft SharePoint has a XSLT 2.0 processor, so you can't use `fn:replace()` because is XPath 2.0. If you describe what you want to replace and for what, we will provide you an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: Actually .NET Framework AFAIK has no XSLT 2.0 support built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace) function is only available in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0).**

AFAIK SharePoint doesn't use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: hi Dimitre. i have a telephone number that can come in any form, which i need to transform into the following format +99(9)99-999-9999 thanks for the help.

Comment: @JadedEric: Please, give a complete example: input, desired output.

Comment: thanks dimitre, but i'll just force the users to type in the telephone number in the desired output, this is becoming to tedious a task.

Answer (score 0):

Waldek Mastykarz has written on the way you can extend CQWP with custom functions. See [Extending Content Query Web Part XSLT with custom functions](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/extending-content-query-web-part-xslt-custom-functions/)